# Integration of trigonometry

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate:

$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1+\cos(x)}{1-\cos(x)}+\dfrac{1+\sin(x)}{1-\sin(x)}dx$

My attempt is to multiply each side by $\dfrac{(1-\cos(x))}{(1-\cos(x))}$ and the other side by $\dfrac{(1-\sin(x))}{(1-\sin(x))}$ so it becomes $\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{(1-\cos(x))^2}+\dfrac{\cos^2(x)}{(1-\sin(x))^2} $from this point I am stuck.

Comment: [MSE-$\texttt{MathJax}$-$\LaTeX$ Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I can't see any importance of integrating sum of two functions when you can easily integrate the two functions separately as hinted by lab .

Answer (score 0):

Using  $\cos2u=1-2\sin^2u=2\cos^2u-1,$

$$\dfrac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}=\dfrac{1+2\cos^2\dfrac x2-1}{1-\left(1-2\sin^2\dfrac x2\right)}=\cot^2\dfrac x2=\csc^2\dfrac x2-1$$

Set $x=\dfrac\pi2-y\iff y=?$ to find $$\dfrac{1+\sin y}{1-\sin y}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}=\dfrac{(1+\cos x)^2}{\sin^2x}=\csc^2x+\cot^2x+2\csc x\cot x$$

$$\dfrac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}=\dfrac{(1+\sin  x)^2}{\cos^2x}=\sec^2x+\tan^2x+2\sec x\tan x$$